# SQL DB copy - server to server

Tags: sql-server, iis-7

I have copied over a database from SERVER 1 to SERVER 2.

All users and necessary security has been copied over.

However when I try and point the online system that uses the database to SERVER 2 instead of SERVER 1 I get a login error (see below image)

[image]

I have made the necessary changes to the web.config file and the user has been checked and all seems fine.

can anyone suggest anything else that needs to be checked?

Comment: how did you copy the security and login?

Comment: by using a script....  Sp_Help_RevLogin.

Comment: have you remove all the users in server2 before adding the users.  Or try manually add one user and see if the is the same and check the users are in their proper account group

Comment: have you set the password of TWAdmin to the same value as the first server ?

Comment: yep.  All that has been set up identically